# html5 canvas won't do anything (I'm new)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
MyCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
MC = MyCanvas.getContext('2d');

RecProCanvas = document.getElementById('recproductioncanvas');

RPC = RecProCanvas.getcontext('2d');


function LoadCanvas() {
//Code I want to execute. (For this I usually use RCP or MC.
}

window.addEventListener("load", LoadCanvas, false);
```

So I wanted to make two simple canvas's, but neither of them will do anything. Is it impossible to work with both canvas's on the same page?

By the way, when I want to "do something" I usually just want to do something simple like:

```
MC.fillRect (0, 0, 150, 50);
```

Comment: And those `id`s exist in your HTML, for sure, right?

Comment: Yes, they definitely do.

Comment: Link to jsfiddle please.

Comment: Hmm... is there a reason why you are adding an event listener as opposed to running these canvas calls on window load (or document ready)?

Comment: No, I just feel more comfortable I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
  MyCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  MC = MyCanvas.getContext('2d');
  MC.fillStyle='blue';
  MC.fillRect(0,0,150,50);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a simple and complete example.

Comment: @KrokosPro I added the html to my example.  I'm not sure what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

One error I found `RPC = RecProCanvas.getcontext('2d');` getcontext all lover case. Should be getContext...

```
<body>
  <canvas width="200" height="200" id="recproductioncanvas">
  </canvas>

  <canvas width="200" height="200" id="canvas">
  </canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        MyCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        MC = MyCanvas.getContext('2d');

        RecProCanvas = document.getElementById('recproductioncanvas');

        RPC = RecProCanvas.getContext('2d');


        function LoadCanvas() {
//Code I want to execute. (For this I usually use RCP or MC.
        }

        window.addEventListener("load", LoadCanvas, false);

        MC.fillRect (0, 0, 150, 50);
        RPC.fillRect (0, 0, 150, 50);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but that isn't the root problem.

Comment: @KrokosPro well sure works for me, so then I would guess it's something with the elements or something...

Comment: @KrokosPro Also... what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, that could be the case as well... I used Chrome.

Comment: Google Chrome. So have this weird theory that everything is working fine, but I just can't see my canvas's(I have a really sloppy, complex page) That's all that makes sense right now.

Comment: @KrokosPro any console output (Developer Tools in Chrome)?